# PHP: Program isn't working. I dont understand the error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have created this 3 pages forms. 1st is registration, 2nd is entry and exit date and now for the 3rd one, i am trying to give the user to choose between value parking, meet and greet service parking and flexible parking. I created a "pick" button right next to each one of them however, when i click on the button, I check my database and only id and username gets updated, the name of the parking doesn't appear.. here are my codes:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error=true;
$users=$_SESSION['tsmUserName'];
$Parkingname="";
if (isset($_POST['tsmValueaParking'])){
    $name="value Parking";
    $error=false;
}
if (isset($_POST['tsmMeetGreetService'])){
    $name="Meet and Greet Service Parking";
$error=false;
}
if (isset($_POST['tsmFlexible'])){
    $name="Flexible Parking";
    $error=false;
}
if($error==false){
    require_once("connection.php");
            $my_query="INSERT INTO `parking`(`Id`, `name`, `username`) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$users')";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$my_query);
            if($result)
            {
                echo 'thank you';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
}

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="picking" id="picking" method="POST" action="">
<table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h2> Welcome to Tassimo Online Supermarket </h2>
                <hr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="30%" align="left">
                    <label for="tsmdate">Value Parking</label></br></br>
                    Our car park is the closest off car park to both terminals. FREE shuttle bus runs every 10 minutes and gets you to the terminals in 3-5 minutes.
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="button" name="tsmValueaParking" id="tsmValueaParking" value="pick">
                </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="left">
                    <label for="tsmdate">Meet & Greet Service</label></br></br>
                    This is a Meet and Greet Service where you will be met at your departure terminal. Your car will be parked at the secure facility. With this service staff member will meet you at your departure terminal and take your car back to their secure compound. On your return staff member will meet you at the Terminal with your car so you can be on your way home as quickly as possible.
                </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="button" name="tsmMeetGreetService" id="tsmMeetGreetService" value="pick">
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="left">
                    <label for="tsmdate">Flexible</label></br></br>
                    This car park is located just 500 meters away. The bus service runs every 30 mins. Tickets cost $4.50 one way and are available from the driver.
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="button" name="tsmFlexible" id="tsmFlexible" value="pick">
                </td>

                </tr>
            </table>


</form>
```

Comment: Under your `$Parkingname="";` line at the top try adding `$name='test';` and see if it adds into the database. Also, do `print_r($_POST);` and see if what you submit is what you expect.

Comment: @Rasclatt i tried var_dump but it couldn't recognize the $_POST as the array is showing 0.. What do i do :/ i am confused

Comment: Change all your `<input type="button"` to `<input type="submit"` then try and submit again.

Comment: I will just put an answer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely due to your form not submitting properly because of the field types. Change all your:

```
<input type="button"
```

to

```
<input type="submit"
```

Then try and submit again. I think if switch type to submit you will see your `$_POST` work properly.

On a side note, you will want to make sure you are careful to bind parameters if you have user-submitted data. You want to avoid sql injection.